# How to put value from MySQL cell into a variable?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, get, echo

I am trying to get the values from MySQL table into a PHP `$variable`.

That's what I have:

```
.
.
.
$name = "SELECT * FROM offene WHERE id = ".$_GET['id']." AND name";
echo $name;
```

If I have to show more code, let me know.

Comment: And what do you want?

Comment: It is for a reservation system. I need to send the costumer an answere via e-mail. For that I need the variables from the database.

Comment: Do you know about `mysqli` or `PDO`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question shows that ,you are very new at php and mysql . Assuming that you have database MYSQL at backend and connection code .. You may do something as below

```
 $query="SELECT * FROM offene WHERE id = ".$_GET['id']." AND name";
        $rs=mysql_query($query) or die("ERRROR ; may be no database connection"); 
        if(mysql_num_rows($rs)==0)
            die("No rows");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs,MYSQL_BOTH))
            {
            echo $row["tbl_field_name"]; //Here you need to
            // replace tbl_field_name with table field name of your database
            }
```

Comment: Don't use mysql_ because 1) it's deprecated and 2) it's open to SQL injection attack unless you sanitize your inputs, which your example in the answer does not do.

Comment: very correct @BrianKH , but concerning to question ,i am getting confusion to answer from the available options

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague, but here is a general pointer that might help. First, you should use mysqli or PDO and bind your parameters, or you are wide open to sql injection attacks.

Here is an example of your code using mysqli. I assumed your desired database field name is `name`.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','username','password','database');

$query = $mysqli->prepare('
    SELECT * FROM offene
    WHERE id = ?');

$query->bind_param(_GET['id']);
$query->execute();

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($name = $result->fetch_object()) {
        echo $name->name."\n";
    }
}
```